# OSX Launchd: Service exited with abnormal code 255

Tags: macos, bash, .app

I created my own app bundle for OSX Yosemite 10.10.5. It is comprised a top level directory called `Grades.app`. Within this directory is the `Contents` directory. within `Contents` is `Info.plist` file and `MacOS` directory with the executable file `Grades` inside of it. This is my Info.plist file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>           <string>Grades</string>

    <key>Label</key>                <string>com.grades.app</string>

    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>           <string>com.grissino.Grades</string>

    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>          <string>0.1</string>

    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>       <string>0.1</string>

    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>        <string>en</string>

    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>          <string>APPL</string>

    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>    <string>6.0</string>

    <key>CFBundleName</key>             <string>Grades</string>

    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>          <string>Grades</string>

    <key>RunAtLoad</key>                <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When I double click the Grades.app file to run the app, it doesn't open. In the console program i get an error from the system launch deamon (com.apple.xpc.launchd) that says `Service exited with abnormal code 255`. I cannot figure out what is wrong.

This is my executable file, it is a bash shell command file (.sh):

```
#! /bin/bash
# Grades

echo “Grades”
cd /Users/(my name)
cd Documents
cd School
cd class
chmod +x ./dist/functions
./dist/functions
```

The functions file runs when called from terminal with the command `./functions` when i am in that directory.

Comment: Those quotes look suspicious, are they like that in your local file? `echo “Grades”`

Comment: The executable runs fine in terminal. I tried it without that line and it still isnt working correctly. I can open the Grades executable by double clicking it and that works fine. but i cant get grades to open by clicking the Grades.app

Comment: I'm talking about your shell script. It has unicode quotes in it, likely made by TextEdit.

Comment: You seem to be missing an icon... `CFBundleIconFile`. Also, I believe you use `RunAtLoad` for `launchd`-controlled processes only.